# NodeJS 20 showing files as directory using fs module

Tags: node.js, next.js

I've a NextJS 14.0.2 application, and currently running NodeJS v20.9.0. I'm trying to read all the files and folders in a directory recursively, and fetch each one's metadata.
My current code is -

```js
const foldersArr = [];
const filesArr = [];
const fileDetails = fs.lstatSync(path); //for a specified path
//here, list item is a metadata object
if(fileDetails.isDirectory()) {
    foldersArr.push(listItem);
} else {
    filesArr.push(listItem);
}
```

The problem is, `fileDetails.isDirectory()` is returning **true** for all folders **and** files, whereas it should return **false** for files.
Repository for my code - https://github.com/rohithandique/next-file-system
I'm not sure what the issue is, and if any more information is required, do let me know. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Note to others.  The relevant code is here: https://github.com/rohithandique/next-file-system/blob/56896661158ee8d483f241a1a949cceec1b68a2f/src/utils/crudData.ts#L1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your actual code, you're doing this:

```
const fileDetails = fs.lstatSync(path);
```

But, `path` is the directory that you listed, NOT the file that you are iterating over.  So, since you pass your function a directory as the `path` argument, then of course this:

```
const fileDetails = fs.lstatSync(path);
console.log(fileDetails.isDirectory());
```

will always log true because `path` is the parent directory you called `fs.promises.readdir(path)` on, not the individual files within that directory.

Note, if you pass the `withFileTypes` argument to `fs.promises.readdir(path, {withFileTypes: true})`, then you will get the `fs.DirEnt` in the first iteration.

---

Here's a plain Javascript version you can execute directly in nodejs to illustrate (just set the variable `testPath` to whatever directory you want to iterate):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const testPath = "somefullpath";

const getDirectoryData = async (pathToList) => {
    const items = await fs.promises.readdir(pathToList, {withFileTypes: true});
    const foldersArr = [];
    const filesArr = [];
    for (const item of items) {
        const listItem = {};
        listItem.name = item.name;
        const fullPath = path.join(pathToList, item.name);
        const stats = await fs.promises.lstat(fullPath);
        listItem.size = stats.size;
        listItem.user = stats.uid === 0 ? "root" : stats.uid;
        if (item.isDirectory()) {
            foldersArr.push(listItem);
        } else {
            filesArr.push(listItem);
        }
    }
    return {folders: foldersArr, files: filesArr};
}

getDirectoryData(testPath).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: yes, this was a mistake from my path, thank you so much, i understood what you wrote.
i imported the `path` module, and inside `fs.lstatSync`, i put the argument as `path.resolve(parsedPath, item` where parsedPath was the "path" i incorrectly put as argument before.
thank you!